# unicodecsv doesn't read unicode csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

This is the line I'm trying to read:

```
with open('u.item', 'w') as demofile:
    demofile.write(
        "543|Mis\xe9rables, Les (1995)|01-Jan-1995||"
        "http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mis%E9rables%2C%20Les%20%281995%29|
        "0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0\n"
    )
```

This is the way I am reading it

```
import unicodecsv as csv
def moviesToRDF(csvFilePath):
    with open(csvFilePath, 'rU') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile,  encoding='utf-8', delimiter= '|')
        for row in reader:
            print row
moviesToRDF("u.item")
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

the value that throws the error is:

```
Misérables, Les
```

What wrong did I do please?

(i am using 2.7 python)

Comment: You sure it's utf-8 encoded?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist i am not sure, how can I know please?

Comment: I extracted the one line that gives you a problem. It is not encoded as UTF-8, you have Latin-1 data instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i had discovered that and had written answer :)

Comment: In future, please include the data **here**, not in an external download. Stack Overflow expects questions to have lasting value; external downloads have a different lifetime, making your question useless for future visitors.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is correct, i will consider that for future. thank you

Comment: Also, and I can't stress this enough: **test** your posted code before hitting *Post Your Question* button. And include the full traceback. This is all part of producing a proper [mcve].

Comment: @MartijnPieters I surely will do, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

the file is encoded latin-1 not utf 8

this solves the problem

```
reader = csv.reader(csvFile,  encoding='latin-1', delimiter= '|')
```